# What does "I think the night hits in the post" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms, listening, sentence

> I think the knight hits in the post

[Link](https://youtube.com/shorts/9_Tu2SzGNZI?si=Ro_4eTVj2zD5whBM) (last sentence of the video)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELL is not a transcription service

Comment: Context? Name of video? Who is this Knight? Is it *night* spelled without a "K"?  Is it part of a song? A poem? Did you transcribe the sentence correctly?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Michael Harvey voted to close this question without watching the video to its end. (He thought it's advertising) Sometimes, it seems like you vote based on your personal preferences rather than the content itself. Could you please clarify the specific rules you are referencing and where they can be found, such as the paragraph or section?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Did you watch the video linked as a context?

Comment: I'm saying you should give **some context**. Why?  because videos are sometimes deleted from YouTube, links sometimes rot, and sometimes people are working in an office and cannot risk having a youtube video blasting at all volume. Now... in my opinion many EL&U contributors are either retired or only visit EL&U when they have free time but you never know, do you? You blame users for not watching a video until the end; well, how long did it take you to write that question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't blame anyone, and you never mentioned what your idea is. However, don't you think your comment is somewhat mean? You cannot vote to close just because you don't accept a video as context.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, if there is a rule that suggests videos are not acceptable as context, just tell me and I will DELETE my question.

Comment: Did you read my explanation why adding context is a good thing? The video is the *source*, it provides the context, but you didn't even say what the video was about. A detail which you could have provided in the first place. Just spending an extra five minutes meant I would not have cast my vote to close the question because it lacks detail. Which it does, you cannot deny it is a fact. Fumble Fingers's first comment is also pertinent.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Even if I write it, your friends will react with 'We have never seen this in our entire lives.'"

Comment: @Mari-LouA By the way, Thank you. I will delete this post. Happy now?

Comment: I don't think I am being harsh or mean. I never said or suggested your question should be deleted. What you could have done was to provide some of those details I suggested, and as I am often wont to do, I would have retracted my down/close vote. If you look at my profile page, the number of upvotes I cast is far higher than downvotes. You're still in time to add just two or more details. But it's your choice. The system prevents users from deleting a question once it has received an answer, been accepted and it has also been upvoted.

Comment: [Please, everyone ... details. Please!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Comment: Questions tagged **transcription** - [*For questions about the representation of speech sounds with phonetic symbols. Note that English Language Learners **is NOT a transcription service**; those kind of questions are **generally off-topic and are therefore often closed.***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcription)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benedict Cumberbatch says '**the knighthood's in the post**'. He is being sarcastic about Depp forgetting Queen Camilla's name. If we say something, e.g. an award, prize, or honour is 'in the post' (on its way, in the mail) we can mean that the thing is assured or certain to happen. In any case Depp cannot have a knighthood, as he is not a UK citizen.